# define `delete` or any other reserved word function in d.ts file

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to create a d.ts file for codebooks.io, which defines `delete` as a top level exported function.

https://codehooks.io/docs/appeventapi#appdeleteroute-callback

here is my `codebooks-js.d.ts` file so far

```
declare module "codehooks-js" {
    export type Method = 'GET' | 'HEAD' | 'POST' | 'PUT' | 'DELETE' | 'CONNECT' | 'OPTIONS' | 'TRACE' | 'PATCH' 

    export type RequestObject = {
        headers: Object,
        query: Object,
        params: Object,
        body: any,
        path: string,
        apipath: string,
        originalUrl: string,
        method: Method,
        hostname: string,
    }

    export type ResponseObject = {
        set: (header: string, value: string) => void,
        headers: (object: Object) => void,
        status: (httpStatusCode: number) => void,
        json: (object: Object) => void,
        write: (data: string | unknown) => void,
        send: (data: string) => void,
        end: () => void,
    }

    export type Next = () => void

    export type Callback = (request: RequestObject, response: ResponseObject, next: Next) => void

    export function init(): void
    export function use(callback: Callback): void
    export function get(route: string): void
    export function get(route: string, callback: Callback): void
    export function post(route: string, callback: Callback): void
    export function put(route: string, callback: Callback): void
    export function patch(route: string, callback: Callback): void

    // here's the problem
    export function delete(route: string, callback: Callback): void
}
```

typescript error given

> Identifier expected. 'delete' is a reserved word that cannot be used here.ts(1359)

I expected to be able to use `@ts-expect-error` but that doesn't seem to do anything in d.ts file.

how can I work around this?

Comment: As the error says, `delete` is a keyword in Javascript/Typescript and can't be used as an identifier.

Comment: Note that all `//@ts-ignore-error` or its siblings do is suppress error messages.  If your car is out of fuel, covering up the warning light with duct tape will suppress the message but it will not put fuel in the tank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rename exports in [an `export` statement](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#export-statements) like `export { internalName as externalName }`, and luckily `delete` is not considered a reserved identifier in such a rename.  So you can write this:

```
function _delete(route: string, callback: Callback): void;
export { _delete as delete } // no error
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKAJgpgxgNghgJwgAgLYHswFcYoERSYQAW66A1gM4C0AVpXsgN6jJvIQAeADuggC7J+AT24oAshH6kwyALzIA5AHEAogBVFyAD5KAEqoCCAES27FABQDyAZU06lFgKr3zx1QBkNqs0oDCVgBygap+rkpWFuoAkkE2vorqAEqGfj4OlobqfnqKoKzsXLwCQqIoSRAAjlgQlPxWAEa00IIKLCDsncjEEHCQCJQAXMiNzVD8ADQFXcjVEAjCw6MtUx0zyNyIcKhDI00r010NmIvIcAB2wqvrG3DSw3UIAJbnAObX63DcT5v3yI8vd6HTp8J6vF5wGBOBAwB78Z5vD4zVBSGTDSTSTBIrqkOrnbYQOEIoFrNgAX3ypI4PD4ghEYmQFUovHOlAgy3G8mYwPYbP4wwAFD0+vMiYCJsgAG6Qmpit4ASnkAD4pegnmBsZ1hf1dgL0PtxksDfxFXIVZK1RqeWw6ncsLriPx+NwbPw7ZQ-ERhucsKgGvNTebLZr2PR0OdBfqxvy9tHA6r1SG2AB3Z78QnIAVgO5wOWvBxYc7kc7oZPneMWxPW-4Qc5gQXZt15ivB6u1+uZltVqkUkCHIq00oMwJcVqd5UJsCUzoDkr0lB+SEwBpwKDkLkCpBzOrDCrb+rGiVIZnhtm72ostkcybIc6j4YjzgmieVqd9qmzwQAM0L4ye4eQF4nn4AV5WGV9+xpEof3OP8APtCABSgJcVzXYZFxgZdV3IMDJ0g4pv1-fh-3OZBXikTd0CwdNm3Ay18MHGC4NI8iQIQKiaP+eFxWQZDMNQ8h0JQ7DcIgj8oMI2DiIA3g6ko6iMwBRFeOEtDkAwrC11E+jxII5AmOk0juGo+TOKU94VP47ChKsrS6PVBjoKIkjbn4KBiFMxTuOUvjNME9TVJw+y30OAyXIAfUgXB008vMJV8gSbL87T1QAbkcwQmGQSKIGilA4EoZAoqkFBe17UAgA)